# Prove that there are no entire function satisfying $|f(z)|\ge |\cos(z)|+|\sin(z)|$ for all $z\in \Bbb C$

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

Hi. I need to prove that  there are no entire function satisfing  $$|f(z)|\ge|\cos(z)|+|\sin(z)| \\\forall z\in\mathbb{C}.$$
I think I need to use the *Liouville theorem*.
 Appriciate any help, Thanks!

Comment: Could $f$ have zeros?

Comment: I think yes. nothing told about f having zeros

Comment: Well, you have a lower bound on $\lvert f(z)\rvert$. Look at that again.

Comment: but it can be that |cos(z)| + |sin(z)| is not bounded right?

Comment: Velcome to the site!

Comment: @david It is not bounded, but that is not (yet) relevant. It is a _lower_ bound. If $f$ satisfied that condition, _could it have zeros_?

Comment: no. it could not have any zeros.

Comment: o.k so maybe it can develop to contradiction of f image being dense?

Comment: Well, why not think about your original hunch? If $f\ne 0$, to what function perhaps might Liouville apply?

Comment: Liouville will applay g(z)=1/f(z)

Answer (score 2):

A hint:

One has $|\cos(x+iy)|^2=\cos^2 x+\sinh^2 y$ and a similar formula for $|\sin(x+iy)|^2$. Use this to obtain an estimate $|f(z)|\geq C>0$.

Now argue about the function $$g(z):={1\over f(z)}\ .$$

Answer (score 2):

The identity $\cos^2 z + \sin^2 z = 1$ still holds when $z$ is complex. So always either
$|\cos^2 z| \geq {1 \over 2}$ or $|\sin^2 z| \geq {1 \over 2}$, which in turn implies that
$$|\cos z| + |\sin z| \geq {1 \over \sqrt{2}}$$
So you have an entire function satisfying
$$|f(z)| \geq {1 \over \sqrt{2}}$$
Now use Liouville's theorem in the right way...

Answer (score 0):

$$|\cos z|=\left| \frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2} \right|=\frac{|z|}2|\cos\alpha|$$
$$|\sin z|=\left| \frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2} \right|=\frac{|z|}2|\sin\alpha|$$

where $\alpha=\arg(z)$.

Since $|\cos\alpha|+|\sin\alpha|\geq 1$, we have that $|\cos z|+|\sin z|\geq|z|/2$

Moreover, $|\cos 0|+|\sin 0|=1$, so $|f(z)|\geq1$. There exists some $\delta>0$ such that $|f(z)|>1/2$ for $|z|<\delta$. Let be $C=\min\{\delta/2,1/2\}$.

Therefore, $|f(z)|\geq C$ for all $z\in\Bbb C$, which contradicts strong Picard's theorem. Or, if you prefer, $1/|f|$ is bounded above by $1/C$, and $f$, by Liouville's theorem, is constant, and this is impossible since $|\cos z|+|\sin z|$ is not bounded above (as we have just proven).